# How to change starting cell order in a subplot in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a subplot figure. As you know, by default, subplots are indexed from the top-left of the diagram. Yet, I need to change this indexing to the bottom-left. How can I do that?

The following figure represents the current version that I get from plotly (i.e., indexing started from top-left):

[image]

The following figure indicates the desired version (i.e., subplots are indexed from bottom-left):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the last version of plotly (version 5.16), you can easily do it by setting the property of `start_cell` when you are making the subplot, like as follows:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# default value of the start_cell is "top-left"
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, start_cell="bottom-left")
```